# multithreading in codeblocks

Tags: code-blocks

I tried to implement multithreading using codeblocks in ubuntu.
I typed the following program.

```
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{

    sleep(1);
    printf("Printing hi from Thread \n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{

    pthread_t tid;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

But I couldn't compile and run the program in codeblocks.
I got the following error

```
multithread.c  undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
multithread.c  undefined reference to 'pthread_join'
```

can someone help me out

I had used the following header files in the code:

```
pthread.h
stdio.h
stdlib.h
```

Answer (score 4):

In Code::Blocks if you are using the GNU `gcc` compiler, you will probably need to add the `-pthread` compiler flag to both the compiler and linker options (under `Project --> Build options...)

[image: Code::Blocks compiler options]

[image: Code::Blocks linker options]

Comment: Works fine in Code Blocks 13.12, Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to make sure that you installed the pthread librarys correctly. You can find it in the software center under "libpthread-stubs0-dev" or simply install by doing :

`sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev`.

Also I didn't really understand at firt that you just have to type in -pthread manually...

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662909/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create-in-linux), the problem is not with codeblocks and not with the compiler either. Problem seems to be with the linker, i tried your code in eclipse, i get the same error if i am not using:

```
gcc -pthread -o multithread multithread.c
```

Hope that helps. Read more [here](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).