# Using matplotlib-cpp in Code::Blocks

Tags: python, compiling, c++, code-blocks

I am trying to use matplotlib-cpp according to this guide:
[Installing matplotlib-cpp](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fdownload.acadox.com%2Fresource%2F57111%2F141661.pdf%3FAWSAccessKeyId%3DAKIAJM4VSPRIVX3JQ6WQ%26Expires%3D1570805450%26Signature%3D7EzNAU%252Bg4917HQJSdfUKKYuL%252Fnw%253D), but I am trying it on Ubuntu so It's a little bit different.

In "Search directories", I have included these two to "Compiler":

```
/usr/local/include/python2.7 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy
```

And for "Linker" I have included:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
```

In "Linker settings" section, I have added:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a
```

I am getting 28 errors. Here are some of them:

```
/usr/src/Python-2.7.16/Python/dynload_shlib.c|94|undefined reference to `dlsym'|
/usr/src/Python-2.7.16/Python/thread_pthread.h|225|undefined reference to `pthread_create'|
/usr/src/Python-2.7.16/Python/thread_pthread.h|301|undefined reference to `sem_init'|
/usr/src/Python-2.7.16/./Modules/posixmodule.c|4022|undefined reference to `forkpty'|
```

What is missing?

Comment: Have you added `-pthread` to both compiler and linker flags/options?

Comment: @steeldriver, how should I do it?

Comment: Please see [multithreading in codeblocks](https://askubuntu.com/a/568092/178692)

Comment: Sounds like you need to add `libdl` to the list of libraries as well - in `gcc` that would be as simple as adding `-ldl` to the command line, unfortunately I don't use code::blocks so you will need to figure that part out yourself

Comment: I accidentally deleted the comment, but thanks. I will search for that

Comment: @steeldriver, okay I did it. Another error appears but in Xterm

'ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import'

Do you have any idea how to fix it?